# flutter dio reset password API integrating not working

Tags: flutter, api, dio

below is the code I implement to send email when click Reset password button. but its not working properly. when I enter already registered email it says "No User Found". it should display"Please check your email to reset password". how to solve this issue

[postman request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/goUpv.png)

```
class _LoginFormState extends State<SignUpForm> {
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  //String _userName = "";
  String email = "";

  Future Resetpassword() async{
    try {
      var response = await Dio().post('https://app2-hi.herokuapp.com//user/forgotpassword',data:

    {
    "email": email,
    }
    );

    if(response.data["message"] == " Please check your email to reset password."){
    Get.snackbar("success","Email Sent Sucessfully!");
  

    }else{
    Get.snackbar("error", "No User Found");
    }
    print("res: $response");
    } catch (e) {

    Get.snackbar("error", "No User Found");
    print(e);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why did you write response.data["message"]. It should be **response.data["data"]** as the response parameter you receive is called **data**.

```
  if (response.data["data"] == "Please check your email to reset password.") {
    Get.snackbar("success","Email Sent Sucessfully!");
  } else {
    Get.snackbar("error", "Email Not Sent. Please try again.");
  }
    print("res: ${response.data}");
  } catch (e) {
    Get.snackbar("error", e.toString());
    print(e);
  }
```

Comment: ok sir. thank you but that's not solving the error.

Comment: Then your code is actually moving to catch. Try using different error message for catch. All check what response is getting printed in res:

Comment: did you check the postman response image in the question. kindly tell me the way to correct this.

Comment: Please check my answer again. I edited it. Plus you have an extra space in "Please check your email......", that is why the string never matches the response from api.

Comment: DioError [DioErrorType.response] Http status error [404] ..Im getting this error when I enter registered email address

Comment: Then you have a problem with your API.

Comment: its worked after restarting the project thank u